# Find position where the member of two lists differs

Tags: python

I have the following two lists of strings with the same size:

```
l1 = ['foo', 'foo','bar','cho']
l2 = ['foo', 'qux','bar','cxx']
              *           *
```

What I want to do is to find the position where the members differs,
yielding:

```
1, 3
```

How can we do that?

Comment: What did you try so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use list comprehension:

```
>>> [i for i, v1 in enumerate(l1) if v1 != l2[i]]
[1, 3]
```

This will iterate over the first list, and compare the values with the second list, and incase they do not match, adds the index to the result.

Answer (score 1):

When iterating over 2 lists of the same size, use [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip):

```
diff = [i for i, (x, y) in enumerate(zip(l1, l2)) if x != y]
```